# wp_query, give first post different formatting

Tags: wp-query

I want to be able to give the first post in a custom instance of `wp_query` different formatting to the rest.

This is a sample of my current loop (With some bits simplified to shorten my code);

```
$args1 = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 4
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    echo '<h2><a href="'.the_permalink().'">'.the_title().'</a></h2>';
endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
```

But for the first post in this loop I want to formatting to be different so that I can show the post thumbnail, a short content excerpt, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope I'm understanding you correctly could you not just do something simple like this

```
$args1 = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 4
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
while ($loop->have_posts()) : 
    $loop->the_post();
    echo '<h2><a href="'.the_permalink().'">'.the_title().'</a></h2>';
    if ($loop->current_post == 0) {
          echo the_post_thumbnail();
          echo the_excerpt();
    }
endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: You don't have to create your own variable to count posts. `wp_query` has `current_post` which does exactly the same ;)

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that have updated with your suggestion.